# Show one div and hide the other by checked radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to learn how to use jquery to show/hide elements dependent on values. i'm not sure if .show / .hide is the right choice so any help will be appreciated...

Here is my example on [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrf32dkd/) where I have 2 radio buttons and 2 divs.

I want Jquery to show a single div by the dependency of the `checked` radio button, so it will show **only** the one that is checked.

*HTML*:

```
 <input type="radio" name="one" value="01" checked> Male<br>
 <input type="radio" name="two" value="02"> Female<br>

<div class="showhide">
show me when 01 is checked.
</div>

<div class="showhide">
show me when 02 is checked.
</div>
```

*JQuery* (trying to understand what to do here):

```
$("div.showhide").hide();
$("div.showhide").show();

// or maybe with:

$("div.showthis").toggle(this.checked);
```

Comment: Sorry, fixed the wrong details..  about the logic, my intention is to make it work without reloading the page, should I use  `$(function() {}` ?

Comment: You would use an event binding to handle for user changes.  Take a look at the answer below for an example of a change event binding.  Though personally i'd put a class on the radio buttons to select on rather than doing `[type="radio"]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `data-*` attributes comes in handy in such practices. Rember that the radios `name` attributes must be the same that one and only one checkbox can be checked at any given time. And, there is no `p` tag in your code, at least in the example provided, so why bother prefixing the selector with it?

The following example makes use of `data-section` attribute which has the selector for the element that must be shown when the checkbox is checked. It is worth mentioning that this is code is dynamic and does not require changing the code when adding more inputs with divs.

```js
$(function() {
    
    // listen for changes
    $('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function(){
        
        // get checked one            
        var $target = $('input[type="radio"]:checked');
        // hide all divs with .showhide class
        $(".showhide").hide();
        // show div that corresponds to selected radio.
        $( $target.attr('data-section') ).show();

    // trigger the change on page load
    }).trigger('change');

});
```

```css
.showhide {  
   display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="one" data-section="#div-1" value="01" checked>Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="one" data-section="#div-2" value="02">Female<br>

<div id="div-1" class="showhide">
show me when 01 is checked.
</div>
<div id="div-2" class="showhide">
show me when 02 is checked.
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but, it my question was on how to show the `div` that is `checked`, and I mean even when page loads with it...

Comment: @Hakerovsky on Adam code and at the end of `change` event code add `.change()`